# How do multi-line regex replace in bash and store in variable?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line

I want to do multi-line replace using regex in a bash script and store that value in a variable. The following does *not* work:

```
str="line 1 replace_me
line 2 replace_me"

D="${D/replace_me/new_value}"
echo $D
```

I get the result:

> line 1 new_value
>   line 2 replace_me

So only the first line gets it replaced. How can i set flags for this (global, multiline) or use a diff regex way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding another slash makes it a global search:

```
str="line 1 replace_me
line 2 replace_me"

echo "${str//replace_me/new_value}"
```

Output:

```
line 1 new_value
line 2 new_value
```